# What cross-platform online training solutions are available?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-streaming

I am looking for a solution to do my online computer trainings to users over the internet. For these trainings I need to share my screen as well as having a platform for the voice and people to ask questions. I don't need fancy stuff like blackboard, etc.

For my previous training I used Yuuguu for screen sharing which works very well and Wiziq for chat/voice (although a bit costly). The very good thing with Yuuguu is that it does not consume my processing resources, however, the maximum number of users is 30.

So, Can you suggest firstly a better all in one solution (screen/voice/chat)? If not a better alternative to Yuuguu (the same price range preferably unlimited number of users) and Wiziq (a free chat/voice preferably). The clients can have any kind of OS and I use Ubuntu and sometimes windows.

Comment: I have seen use of  teamviewer in similar situations have you tried that  it might help you  also skype has the ability to share screen I do not know about user limit in skype

Comment: @RegisteredUser, now I use wiziq to share my screen in windows. I will try teamviewer if I were forced to use Linux. Skype is not good for any number more than 10, even 5.

Answer (score 1):

We used to have the skype and teamviewer for our [java training course in chennai](http://wisentechnologies.com/it-courses/java-training.aspx).

karthick

Comment: how many people were in class? Could you provide more details?